# Dunnett test for mixed effect model of incomplete block design in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, posthoc, lmertest

(First question here on SO, apologies for any mistakes!)

I'm trying to analyse data with a linear mixed model accounting for block (Plot) and genotype (Line) effects with Welch-Satterthwaite adjustment of degrees of freedom to account for the different replication rate of WT (control). This is an incomplete block design, with the WT included in each block.

I've used `lmerTest::lmer`, to build the model

```
library(lmerTest)

biomass.lmer <- lmer(sqrt(Leaf_area) ~ Line + (1 | Plot) ,
                     data = biomass.allmeans)
anova(biomass.lmer)
```

So far, so good. The Satterthwaite correction for df is taken into account. 
But when I try to then do a post-hoc Dunnett test

```
dunnett.test <- glht(anova(biomass.lmer), linfct = mcp( Line = "Dunnett"), alternative = "two.sided") 
summary(dunnett.test)
```

It does not work. `glht` cannot handle an S4 object as returned by `lmerTest::anova`. However, `lmerTest::lmer` as well as `lme4::lmer` do return a valid object, but the latter can't take into account the Satterthwaite correction.

---

**Question**

Am I missing something? Any suggestions on how to turn the anova of the corrected model into a valid object or use a different way to do a Dunnett test with an S4 object are very much appreciated.

---

As suggested, the data (biomass.allmeans):

```
structure(list(Line = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("WT", "11-008", 
"14-005", "2-94", "7-028", "8-93"), class = "factor"), Plot = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
9L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 
9L, 11L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), Leaf_area = c(3579.5, 
3316.25, 4018.25, 3381, 3697.75, 2938.75, 2487.75, 1529.25, 2514.75, 
2713.5, 2037.5, 3696.25, 3350, 1790.75, 1270, 2706.75, 2517.25, 
4715, 3409.75, 3488.75, 2583.75, 1863, 1749.25, 2001, 2530.25, 
3012, 3514.25, 2871.25, 1740.75, 2745.25, 3279, 2826.5, 3744.25, 
1297.25, 1123.75, 691.5, 1263, 684.666666666667, 891.25, 873.5, 
1461, 5217.75, 4867.25, 4629.75, 3748, 2693.75, 1615.5, 4407)), .Names = c("Line", 
"Plot", "Leaf_area"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
```

Comment: Overall, great clear first question - just one suggestion - could you use `dput()` to share your data (or a subset of your data, if the whole dataset is too large) so your example is reproducible?

Comment: Are you using `lmerTest::ranova` or `anova` from another library? I don't see a `lmerTest::anova` function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I used `lmerTest::anova` as this includes the Satterthwaite correction. According to the documentation, this is also called `anova.lmerModLmerTest`?

Answer (score 0):

I see `anova.lmerModLmerTest` in its `namespace` but I can't access it for some reason. `R` doesn't think the function exists. Sorry, I can only run it with `stats::anova`, but I'm not sure that's the actual problem. `?glht` is looking for a model. So if I just run it with the `lmer` model it works.

```
stats::anova(biomass.lmer)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
     Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
Line 4131.8  826.36     5 33.434  18.084 1.146e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Significant results, including the Satterthwaite correction for df, so run the post-hoc.

```
dunnett.test <- glht((biomass.lmer), linfct = mcp(Line = "Dunnett"), alternative = "two.sided")

 General Linear Hypotheses
Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts

Linear Hypotheses:
                 Estimate
11-008 - WT == 0  -0.6996
14-005 - WT == 0  -5.1471
2-94 - WT == 0    -0.2379
7-028 - WT == 0  -23.7876
8-93 - WT == 0     7.5590

summary(dunnett.test)

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts

Fit: lmer(formula = sqrt(Leaf_area) ~ Line + (1 | Plot), data = biomass.allmeans)

Linear Hypotheses:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
11-008 - WT == 0  -0.6996     3.2885  -0.213   0.9998    
14-005 - WT == 0  -5.1471     3.2885  -1.565   0.4198    
2-94 - WT == 0    -0.2379     3.2885  -0.072   1.0000    
7-028 - WT == 0  -23.7876     3.1372  -7.582   <0.001 ***
8-93 - WT == 0     7.5590     3.2885   2.299   0.0943 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. When using `stats::anova` it works with `glht`, but does not include the Satterthwaite correction that I am after (as with `lmerTest::anova`).

Comment: I'm perplexed as to why I can't access that function, so I can't see exactly what error is produced. What error are you getting? I'm also not sure I fully understand. `lmerTest::lmer` provides the Satterthwaite correction for your `df` to generate the model getting passed to `glht` to complete the post-hoc test, so the correction is included. `anova` should need the same thing, a type of linear model, so I don't know of how it could work if you input `anova` results.